# Graphics: File name won't go away

Tags: graphics, captions

I've just learned how to insert pictures using the \includegraphics{} command. In the compiled PDF document, the file name is visible immediately below the image.

Is there a way to suppress the file name? (see the red arrows below)

[image]

Comment: Does this only happen for file names that contain spaces?

Comment: Also, please to *not* use ``\\`` in the text, use proper paragraphs.